# Ubuntu LiveCD/LiveUSB Default Login Credentials

Tags: linux, ubuntu, livecd

I've just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04, created a USB startup drive, and booted. What is the default username and password for the live USB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default username is `ubuntu`.

The default password is empty.  (This is why you can `sudo` without entering a password.)